# How to add several dependent records with LINQ2SQL

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have two tables. One table contains comments on posts, another contains commenter information like nickname, site, etc..
There is FK relations betwin two tables
Comment.CommenterId -> Commenter.Id
Whenever user posts a comment I need to add comment and commenter at the same time.
The problem is that I don't know what would be Commenter.Id after addition to assign it to Comment.CommenterId before addition.

What is the best practice to do such inserts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this like so:

```
Comment comment = new Comment(); // your constructor here
Commenter commenter = new Commenter(); // use your constructor;

comment.Commenter = commenter; // linq2sql creates this property for you.

datacontext.Commenter.InsertOnSubmit(commenter);
datacontext.Comment.InsertOnSubmit(comment);

datacontext.SubmitChanges();
```

this code has not been tested here in any way, so there may be syntax or other errors, but this is basically what you would need to do.

Comment: You do not need the InsertOnSubmit(comment) if the tables are associated by a foreign Key