# Linq2Sql Insert Records To Related Tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

Similar situation to : [How to add several dependent records with LINQ2SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630320/how-to-add-several-dependent-records-with-linq2sql) 
(this seems logical, but it doesn't work for me)

ASP.NET MVC + Linq2SQL

I have 2 tables called Challenges and Participants.

- Challenge { challengeId,
  ChallengeDesc, applicantId,
  respondantId }
- Participants { participantId, FirstName, LastName }

There are 1-many relationships between participants and Challenges - 1 for each key (applicantId, RespondantId).

I have an input form that collects all fields to create a new applicant and respondant and the challenge.  The Databinder binds all the fields to Challenge and it's child participants correctly, however, the participant objects' names don't match the key names in the challenge object when browsing the structure created by Linq2Sql (applicantId matches with Participant object and respondantId matches with Participant1 object).

So when i try to SubmitChanges() after InsertOnSubmit(aChallenge) i get a foreign_key constraint validation message back from Linq2Sql. In SQL Server Profiler, I can see that the participants are being created properly, but when the challenge is being saved, the IDs of these newly inserted participants are not being set to the challenge object so the system is throwing a foreign key violation message.

How do i get past this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to write it this way I think (assuming you have classes Participant and Challenge):

```
Participant applicant = new Participant();
Participant respondant = new Participant();
//update your participants here

Challenge insertedChallenge = new Challenge();
//update your challenge values here

applicant.Challenges.add(insertedChallenge);
respondant.Challenges1.add(insertedChallenge);

submitChanges();
```

Linq-to-SQL should automatically assign these properties (Challenges and Challenges) so it can set the key values for you.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to edit you data objects (normally by using the DBML designer) and rename the `Participant`-typed properties to `Applicant` and `Respondent` respectively. It'll be easier to work with than having `Participant` and `Participant1`. You can do this in the association properties (the lines that connect the tables).

When you want to assign the foreign keys in `Challenge`, you have two choices. If you have the `Participant` objects themselves, you can assign them to the (newly renamed) `Applicant` and `Respondent` properties (and LINQ to SQL will update `ApplicantID` or `RespondentID` accordingly). Or if you have the `ParticipantID`s, you can assign them to `ApplicantID` or `RespondentID` directly.