# linq to sql @identity foreign key insertonsubmit

Tags: linq-to-sql

I thought you could do this with linq, but it always throws a foreign key error and the ContactType.id is 0. Is it necessary to call SubmitChanges after inserting the new ContactType, or am I missing something basic?

```
Dim ct As New ContactType
ct.name = "supervisor"
db.ContactTypes.InsertOnSubmit(ct)

Dim c As New Contact
c.ContactTypeId = ct.id
c.first_name = "fname"
c.last_name = "lname"
db.contacts.InsertOnSubmit(c)

db.SubmitChanges()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered by [lucas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/24231/lucas) in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875653/linq2sql-insert-records-to-related-tables)

It is necessary to set the ContactType object, not the foreign key value.

```
Dim ct As New ContactType
ct.name = "supervisor"
db.ContactTypes.InsertOnSubmit(ct)

Dim c As New Contact
c.ContactType = ct 'this is the important line
c.first_name = "fname"
c.last_name = "lname"
db.contacts.InsertOnSubmit(c)

db.SubmitChanges()
```

Thank you Lucas!